# mysql_affected_rows Returns False On Successful Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a difficult time sorting through this PHP/MySQL issue. Let me show you my database, and explain my situation:

---

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `activation` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` longtext NOT NULL,
  `lastName` longtext NOT NULL,
  `passWord` longtext NOT NULL,
  `changePassword` text NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress1` longtext NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress2` longtext NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress3` longtext NOT NULL,
  `role` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`firstName`,`lastName`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Insert a value:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (
  `id` ,
  `active` ,
  `activation` ,
  `firstName` ,
  `lastName` ,
  `passWord` ,
  `changePassword` ,
  `emailAddress1` ,
  `emailAddress2` ,
  `emailAddress3` ,
  `role`
) VALUES (
  NULL,  '1000000000',  'abcdefghijklmno',  'John',  'Smith',  '*24D7FB97963C40FE5C56A6672F9560FC8B681508',  'on',  'john@gmail.com',  '',  '',  'User'
);
```

Update a value:

```
$affected = mysql_query(UPDATE users SET passWord = PASSWORD('a9eb42e1b3be829ef42972ea9abab334'), changePassword = 'on' WHERE emailAddress1 = 'john@gmail.com', $dbID); 

if (mysql_affected_rows($affected)) {
    //Never runs
}
```

The above `UPDATE` query executes just fine in my script, phpMyAdmin, and the MySQL terminal. However, `mysql_affected_rows($affected)` *always* gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I know that this means my query failed, but every time I go into the database, I see that the values have been updated.

Removing the parameter from the function appears to clear things up. However, I rather have the identifier as the function parameter, just to be sure what I am referring to, and for code insurance.

Any idea why this might be doing this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See the manual on `mysql_query()`: this is by design, it will return `true` or `false` after an update. You need to use the connection specifier instead. Side note: You are not doing any error checking after your query. See the manual  to see how to do that.

Comment: you have an error in your query, change PASSWORD('a9eb42e1b3be829ef42972ea9abab334') to \"PASSWORD('a9eb42e1b3be829ef42972ea9abab334')\" and check again

Comment: @mohammadfalahat Adding quotes around PASSWORD(...) would pass it as a literal string.

Comment: @Pekka I have error checking in my actual script, and it passes with no problem.

Comment: I think you have the wrong parameter for mysql_affected_rows, it expects an optional db connection, not the result of a query ? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php says it returns a boolean on updates, not a conn_identifier. Try changing $affected to $dbID ?

Comment: @Pyranja Yes! You totally nailed it. I can't believe that I never did that! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> http://php.net/mysql_query
>
> **Return Values**
>
> ...
>
> For other type of SQL statements, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, etc, `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on error.

And:

> `int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

This means `mysql_affected_rows` wants a mysql connection resource as an argument. Not the result of `mysql_query`, and most certainly not if that result is only `true` or `false`. You use it like this:

```
$successful = mysql_query('UPDATE ...'); 

if ($successful) {
    echo 'Affected rows: ' . mysql_affected_rows();
} else {
    echo 'Fail: ' . mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$affected = mysql_query(UPDATE users SET passWord = PASSWORD('a9eb42e1b3be829ef42972ea9abab334'), changePassword = 'on' WHERE emailAddress1 LIKE 'john@gmail.com', $dbID);
```

and execute

Comment: also you must send db resource link as parameter in mysql_affected_rows, not query

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that the new value of updating was equal to the old value, so no change is made and the result of the `mysql_affected_rows()` would be `0` or `false`